# Replace characters in string with XXXXX in PHP

Tags: php, string, preg-replace

I have string like "This is my 'test' string. 123 \/ !@#"
And i need any easier solution to get newly converted string as "XXXX XX XX XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXX XX XXX".

Each word length should be equal to the 'XXX..' string. Only SPACE between words should be appear as it is. Any other characters should get replaced by 'X'. Is there any easy solution ?

Comment: you really need to show some effort on solving the problem yourself.

Comment: There is no choice when working on parallel projects with no time to explore.

Comment: we're not a coding service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple solution using `preg_replace` function:

```
$str = "This is my 'test' string. 123 / !@#";
$converted = preg_replace("/[\S]/", "X", $str); // [\S] - any non-space character

print_r($converted);
```

The output:

```
XXXX XX XX XXXXXX XXXXXXX XXX X XXX
```

Comment: `[^\s]` = `\S`.,. And also you don't need i modifier.

Comment: Thanks @AvinashRaj